# Does a new Blue Card in the same country resets 18 month period?

Tags: european-union, immigration

I have a question, for which I can't find an answer in the Internet. Right now I live and work in Germany, and I'm a holder of Blau Card for 14 month now.

In the next month I will get a new travel passport from my native country due to expiration, and I will need to get a new Blau Card because of it.

My question is: will this operation reset 18-month period of Blau Card holding needed for visa-exempt basis work in another EU member and qualification period for EU long-term residence permit?

> If you have already held an EU Blue Card in another EU Member State for at least 18 months, you can enter country on a visa-exempt basis in order to work.

> All periods of residence of 18 months or longer with the EU Blue Card count towards the qualification period of EU long-term residence permit

Answer (score 1):

you need to notify government about passport change. No periods should reset.
I also afraid you wrongly understand possibility of working in anopther member state.
You need to get new Blue Card in each new member state. But you can accumulate residence period for EU long-term residence

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yes, I know that I should get new Blue Card in other EU member in case of working there. I'm just worrying about this 18 month period, after which I can do that without getting working permit and so.